# IOS 8 off center

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I am trying to write a minimal program, IOS 8 using XCODE 6.1, I add a label and set it to centre for both horizontal and vertical. But it appears off-centre when I run it, any idea?

[image]

Comment: Did you set a horizontal center constraint?

Comment: Yes, it seems like the ViewController is of different size than the emulator? But I set it to iPhone 6, so I am confused.

Comment: Do you only have a centerX and centerY constraint on this label?

Comment: try disable auto layout and size classes and check